# How to pass the senders email address when opening an attachment in your app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email, attachment

I'm trying to make an app that opens a certain file type when attached to emails.

I know how to get the file path which is passed when the app is launched, but is it possible to also have the sender's email address and subject passed to the app also? Is it already part of the dictionary that is passed in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?

Comment: Why not log the whole dictionary as it comes in? Just call `description` on that dictionary (and pass *that* into `NSLog`)and you'll see exactly what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to log the dictionary: it's all in the Apple documentation ([right here, you're after 'launch options keys')](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728)

I am doubtful what you want can be achieved I'm afraid.